# как сделать текст в нав.панеле посередине

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать текст посередине и как сделать маленькую иконку слева от "Магазин" ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(44, 41, 42);
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <!-- <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/747.png" alt=""> -->
  <div class="nav-list">
    <a href="#">Магазин</a>
    <a href="#">Mac</a>
    <a href="#">Ipad</a>
    <a href="#">Iphone</a>
    <a href="#">Watch</a>
    <a href="#">AirPods</a>
    <a href="#">TV и Дом</a>
    <a href="#">Только в Apple</a>
    <a href="#">Аксессуары</a>
    <a href="#">Поддержка</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(44,41,42);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Или же

```
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: А как иконку(изображение будет ) перед словом «Магазин» сделать ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Berbik первый вариант как раз тот, что нужен если раскомментировать изображение, только ещё добавить align-items: center;